# No option to install Italian language as default on Kubuntu 12.10

Tags: kubuntu, language-support, locale

I have just finished installing Kubuntu 12.10 via Wubi, I am customizing my system and, as you can see from the screenshot down below, there's no option to switch from English to Italian as default language system. How do I fix this? [No option available for switching system language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUAbr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The #kubuntu ( http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2012/10/21/%23kubuntu.html ) is suggesting:

yofel / 17:05

> for now you'll probably best of installing 'kde-l10n-language_code'
>   from muon

In this case kde-l10n-it

```
apt-cache show kde-l10n-it
```

> Description: Italian (it) localization for KDE
>
> This package contains the translation files for all KDE core
>   applications for the language "Italian". Homepage:
>   http://l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=it

Same kind of from the KubuntuForums: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?60590-Can-t-install-other-system-languages